# Example of using schtasks and at to schedule a weekly job, persisting between reboots?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, at

Could anyone give me an example of how to use `schtasks` and `at` on Windows to schedule a weekly job?

In particular, I'd like to know how to make sure this job persists between server reboots, which presumably it won't necessarily do if I just type

Is there a Windows equivalent of the crontab file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT will not persist, but schtasks will.

Example schtasks command to run Frecell on the first sunday of every month (Windows 7)

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MONTHLY /MO first /D SUN /TN GameTime /TR c:\windows\system32\frecell
```