# Does anyone have a Windows “at /every:” example to explain how to setup a batch file to run the first sunday of every month?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, batch, tasks, at

This is the one I have to run first day of the month, but I need to run it the first sunday of every month.

at 13:00 /every:1 D:\DBMaintenance\MySc.bat

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with the `at` command.  It only allows for either EVERY Sunday or NEXT Sunday.

You'll need to use Scheduled Tasks instead.  Either with the gui or via cli.

I'll steal this one from [Hyppy](https://superuser.com/a/258311/16462) as an example:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MONTHLY /MO first /D SUN /TN GameTime /TR c:\windows\system32\frecell
```